# SQL Server - Dúvida procedure e relacao entre tabelas

Tags: sql

Tenho uma procedure em meu BD no qual a mesma efetua cadastro de material no banco de dados, até ai tudo bem, porém na procedure de cadastro eu necessito atualizar uma outra tabela atribuindo a quantidade de material a uma coluna x, ou y dependendo do tipo do material, salvei e executei a procedure.

A relaçao e a seguinte : Vou cadastrar material na tabela "material", e na procedure ele pega o tipo do material pelo parametro @tipoMaterial,e ira somar na coluna da tabela "totColetas" o valor em funçao do material ou seja, se no cadastro de material o tipo do material for Papel(que sera o parametro @tipoMaterial) ele iria somar com o valor atual mais o da coleta atual na coluna totalPapel da tabela totColetas, porém sempre ao executar me retorna o resultado "0 linhas afetadas"..Alguém poderia me dar uma luz ou algum jeito mais facil e melhor de se fazer isso(caso o meu esteja ruim)?

Segue o código da proc :

```
 create proc cadMat /*Cadastra o material no banco de dados Ok!(sistema)*/
@cpfColetor char(12),
@nomeMaterial varchar(30),
@tipoMaterial varchar(8),
@zonaMaterial varchar(10),
@qtdeMaterial float,
@dataRecebimentoMaterial datetime
as
begin
    insert into material values(@nomeMaterial,@tipoMaterial,@zonaMaterial,@qtdeMaterial,@dataRecebimentoMaterial,@cpfColetor,'')
    update coletor 
    set qtdeMatCol +=@qtdeMaterial where cpfCol = @cpfColetor
    update material 
    set material.nomeColMat = coletor.nomeCol from material  join coletor on coletor.cpfCol = material.cpfColMat where material.cpfColMat = @cpfColetor
    update totColetas
    set totalPapel += @qtdeMaterial
end
```

Comment: qual é o seu banco de dados?